# How to set a value to multiple cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I always seem to have problem when it comes to updating values in dataframe. Please help me with the problem below.

I have a dataframe –

```
    name cat  score1  score2
0  name1   A      10      20
1  name2   A      11      22
2  name3   B      33      34
```

Now I want to set all the scores (all fields after column index 1) for cat 'A' to 0, like below:

```
df[df['cat']=='A'].iloc[:,2:] = 0
```

But, the following warning/error –

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

And as expected, values are not updated.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: how about `df.iloc[df['cat']=='A',2:] = 0`?

Comment: @AndrewMascillaro won't work, iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Comment: If you know the column names then `df.loc[df['cat']=='A', ['score1','score2']] = 0` is probably the way to go then

Comment: @ron, try option3 in my answer. You need to put the masked index `df['cat']=='A'`, inside the iloc.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, might be version problem. Using masked index in iloc throw [iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available]

Comment: @AndrewMascillaro This is the simplest way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed with the following solution. Kindly provide your feedbacks.

```
dfCatAScores = df[df['cat']=='A'].iloc[:,2:].applymap(lambda x: 0)
df.update(dfCatAScores)
```

[comment from @Andrew Mascillaro]
This is probably I was looking for – 
If you know the column names then

```
df.loc[df['cat']=='A', ['score1','score2']] = 0
```

is probably the way to go then – Andrew Mascillaro

As of my case, I wanted to use columns by index after an offset, so I did this –

```
df.loc[df['cat']=='A', df.columns[2:]] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of those:

**Option 1:**

```
import numpy as np
df['score1'] = np.where(df['cat']=='A', 0, df['score1'])
```

**Option 2:**

```
df['score1'] = (df['cat']!='A') * df['score1']
```

**Option 3:**

```
df.iloc[(df['cat']=='A'),2:] = 0
```

**Proof -  no error:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'name1', 1: 'name2', 2: 'name3'},
 'cat': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'},
 'score1': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 33},
 'score2': {0: 20, 1: 22, 2: 34}})

df.iloc[(df['cat']=='A'),2:] = 0

print(df)

#     name cat  score1  score2
# 0  name1   A       0       0
# 1  name2   A       0       0
# 2  name3   B      33      34
```

Comment: Option 3 will throw an error. as iloc only accepts integer range. Option 1 will work, but requires looping through column index.

Comment: @ron, where should the error occure? I attached the example I tested it with. And what do you mean with loop?

Comment: By loop, I mean the number of score column is not known in advance. So option 1 operation has to be repeated for each score column.